# Reading a file, line by line, analyzing characters --- C

Tags: c, file, line

I'm trying to read a file one line at a time, print out that line, then analyze each character to determine what to do with it (all the analyzing takes place in the driver, mark it as an error if the character is anything except a letter or number)

My current input file is:

```
Hello$ is
asd
```

So this is what I am doing to read one line at a time:

```
char GetSourceChar() {
  char line[MAXLINE];
  if (changeLine == 1) {
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
      char str1[10];
      sprintf(str1,"%d", row); // convert int to 'string'
      printf("[");
      printf(str1);
      printf("] ");
      fprintf(outFile, "%s", "[");
      fprintf(outFile, "%s", str1);
      fprintf(outFile, "%s", "] ");
      printf("%s", line);
      fprintf(outFile, "%s", line);
      changeLine = 0;
    }
  }     
  char c = line[col];
  if (c == '\r'){
    changeLine = 1;
    row++;
    col = 0;
  }
  col++;
  return c;
}
```

And then this is my output:

```
[0] hello$ hi
         ^
         Incorrect Character
[1] asd
```

Which is exactly what I want it to look like, but if I change my input file to even just a word longer, it doesn't work? I notice that the error occurs where I say

```
char c = line[col]
```

It doesn't return the right character, only \000 so nothing seems to work correctly after that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How big is MAXLINE?  I'm assuming it's a define, but what is the value?

Comment: Where do you define col and what value does it have?

Comment: I define col as a global int initially equals 0

Comment: I guess, most problems come from invisible side effects. Try to use parameters with this function. I guess you call this function a number of times? At a certain moment, fgets() will return NULL, but you continue to use the contents of the buffer, which might be undefined in that moment.

Answer (score 1):

The `line` array is declared locally to `GetSourceChar()` and therefore goes out of scope between calls.  So its contents may (or may not) be overwritten after the function returns, and it may (or may not) contain unexpected values the next time you call the function.

You can fix this by:

- declaring it `static` within the function, or
- declaring it in the calling function and passing it as a parameter, or
- declaring it globally.

Also, you can replace all of this

```
char str1[10];
sprintf(str1,"%d", row); // convert int to 'string'
printf("[");
printf(str1);
printf("] ");
fprintf(outFile, "%s", "[");
fprintf(outFile, "%s", str1);
fprintf(outFile, "%s", "] ");
printf("%s", line);
fprintf(outFile, "%s", line);
```

with

```
printf("[%d] %s", row, line);
fprintf(outFile, "[%d] %s", row, line);
```

Comment: Ok this seemed to partially fix it, but now I realize there is an issue if my input is something like this...

    'Hello$
    asd$'

and then an enter to the next line after asd$...it fails to work in this instance

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone, I think I figured it out! 

     `if (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)`

When I would get to the last line of the file, it would recognize it was null, but it wouldn't get rid of the contents on that line. So it was actually still reading characters from that line repeatedly, forming an infinite loop. I fixed this by checking when it was null, and only reading character while not null. Seems to work!